# Connect 4 in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, forms

I've been trying to create connect 4 (the game) in windows forms applications in C# but I'm kinda struggling to create a method so the coins actually drop and not stay were the user clicks. Also I don't know where should I place the win condition method. Here is my code so far:

```
namespace ConnectFour
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[] gameButtons = new Button[42]; //array of buttons for markers(red and blue)
    bool blue = true; //blue is set to true if the next marker is to be a blue

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "Connect 4";
        this.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;

        for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            this.gameButtons[i] = new Button();
            int x = 50 + (i % 7) * 50;
            int y = 50 + (i / 7) * 50;

            this.gameButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            this.gameButtons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
            this.gameButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.gameButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
            //this.gameButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(index);
            this.gameButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.gameButtons[i].Visible = true;

            gameButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender1, index);
            this.Controls.Add(gameButtons[i]);
        }
    }
    private void buttonHasBeenPressed(object sender, int i)
    {
        if (((Button)sender).BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        {
            if (blue == true)
            {
                ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            blue = !blue;
        }
    }
    private void fourInARow(int a, int b, int c,int d)
    {
        if (gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[b].BackColor && gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[c].BackColor && gameButtons[a].BackColor==gameButtons[d].BackColor)
        {
            if (gameButtons[a].BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the winner is player 1");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the winner is player 2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the second (third?) Connect4 question in the past week.. I am guessing there was an assignment somewhere? @jk485921 - I suggest doing a quick google search for a start. Secondly, it looks like you are simply changing the color of whatever button is pushed (in the entire 42 element array) vs. "dropping" the piece down the column. You are far more ahead of you than simply checking the win condition.

Comment: @Forty3 I've already tried to google it but can't find any help for forms. Also that's what I asked for how to create the method of the coins "dropping" I added the color change just to test it tbh.

Comment: here is part 1 of 3 videos that walks through very process of creating a board and the ability for two people to play. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eD8aeLAhT4 I trust you can convert from VB to C#?

Comment: @Forty3 I don't know what is VB i'm kinda new to coding :)

Comment: The author is pretty slow and takes his time explaining. Most (all?) of the steps he takes are directly transferable to C#. Take your time and you will be fine!

Comment: @Forty3 alright. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before you write any code, you should have an idea of the design and structure of your program. For this game you might start with a high-level flow chart of what should happen, and a sketch of what the UI should look like. This will make it easier to determine which classes you want to create, what properties and methods they should have, and then you can plug them all together. At that point, where to put the `win` code will be clear.

Comment: @RufusL Hey, I've already made a plan. I created the form that is working, now I'm trying to find how to make the "coins" drop somehow, and create the winning condition for vertical only. Then I will extend it to horizontal and diagonally. I'm just struggling to make my code drop the coins instead of appearing where the user clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably figured it out by now, but what I would do is take a look at the `BackColor` of each `Button` below the one the user pressed until we either hit the bottom row or we find a `Button` that doesn't have a "BlanchedAlmond" `BackColor`, and then that's the one we change.

To find a `Button` directly below another one, we just look at the `Button` with an `Index` of 7 more than the current `Index`. And since we pass the `Button` object's index in the `index` argument to our function, we can use that.

Here's a commented code example:

```
private void ButtonHasBeenPressed(object sender, int index)
{
    // Get the button that the user pressed
    var pressedButton = (Button)sender;

    // Only do something if they clicked a "neutral" button
    if (pressedButton.BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
    {
        // The backcolor will be set based on whether or not blue is true or false
        var newBackColor = blue ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;

        // Get the index of the button that the user clicked
        var buttonToChangeIndex = index;

        // From where the user clicked, look down at each button below (index + 7)
        // until we find the last button that has a BlanchedAlmond backcolor
        while (buttonToChangeIndex + 7 < gameButtons.Count() && 
               gameButtons[buttonToChangeIndex + 7].BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        {
                buttonToChangeIndex += 7; // Set to the index to point to this button
        }

        // Now we set that button's backcolor
        gameButtons[buttonToChangeIndex].BackColor = newBackColor;

        // Flip our blue flag
        blue = !blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to do something I created a new method that works but if I click the same column it doesn't work again so, basically, it only works once. I can't post my code on the comment unfortunately, it won't let me cause it's too long. From what I found out, only the color thing works but it doesn't assign the value to the button that actually holds the color.

Comment: ah, ok. the one I posted above works, hopefully it will help.

Comment: I'll just stick to mine, hopefully to manage to fix it but thanks a lot for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you use a one-dimensional array to hold the buttons makes things a little more difficult. Since the layout of this “connect four” game is two-dimensional, it would seem logical to make a two-dimensional array. This will help facilitate the “Drop” in a column. Your current code will need to translate which cells in the one-dimensional array make up a column, namely the one the user clicked.

The code below solves this “Dropping” issue by using a two-dimensional array with a method that gets the ROW index of the next available space in a given column. This method returns the next available open slot index in the given column starting at the bottom and going up or returns -1 if the column is full.

You should seriously consider making a class of tokens/markers/buttons, then another Class that is a game board for these tokens. The logic to see if there are 4 consecutive colors horizontally, vertically and diagonally could possibly be complex. However, this logic would fit perfectly towards a GameBoard Object. In addition, the “GameBoard” object could keep track of all the moves etc…

This will greatly free up your code to focus on the visual aspects of the form and not worry about the logic of the game. I hope this makes sense.

```
Button[,] gameButtons = new Button[7,6]; //array of buttons for markers(red and blue)
bool blue = true; //blue is set to true if the next marker is to be a blue

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Text = "Connect 4";
  this.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
  this.Width = 500;
  this.Height = 500;
  int x;
  int y;

  for (int row = 0; row < gameButtons.GetLength(0); row++) {
    x = 50 + (row % 7) * 50;
    for (int col = 0; col < gameButtons.GetLength(1); col++) {
      y = 50*col + 50;
      Button newButton = new Button();
      newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
      newButton.Name = "btn" + (row + col + 1);
      newButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
      newButton.TabIndex = row + col;
      newButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      newButton.Visible = true;
      newButton.Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender1);
      gameButtons[row, col] = newButton;
      Controls.Add(gameButtons[row,col]);
    }
  }
}

private void buttonHasBeenPressed(object sender) {
  Button buttonClicked = (Button)sender;
  int col = buttonClicked.Location.X / 50 - 1;
  int targetRow = GetButtonRow(col);
  if (targetRow >= 0) {
    if (blue == true) {
      gameButtons[col, targetRow].BackColor = Color.Red;
    } else {
      gameButtons[col, targetRow].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    blue = !blue;
  }
}

public int GetButtonRow(int colIndex) {
  Button curButton;
  for (int row = gameButtons.GetLength(1) - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    curButton = gameButtons[arrayColIndex, row];
    if (curButton.BackColor != Color.Red && curButton.BackColor != Color.Blue) {
      return row;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```